# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hideshare is not a function

Tags: magento2, javascript, theme

I am getting this error when I open single product page. Due to this page is not getting load. I have done some workaround for this... but did not get any clue.

it is theme based issue. I am using Magenest - Couture Fashion theme of Magento.

> 1) Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hideshare is not a function
>
> 2) Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

welcome for any decent solution...

Comment: can you share more info which js file getting error?

Comment: @SanjuAntala,  Basically, when I open a page of product (single product page) then the image of the product is not loading. At that time on console, above error is replicated